# IE11 security certificate issue when using iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, ssl

I am getting the below error when I am trying to open one new window using iFrame and IE11, the new window is having a pdf content. IE7-IE10 looks good. I am using https here.
Error message:

> Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security
>   certificate.  For more information, see “About Certificate Errors” in
>   Internet Explorer Help.

My Code goes here:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1){
    var html = "<html><head><title></title>";
    html += "</head><body style='margin: 0;'>";
    html += "<iframe height='100%' width='100%' src='" + finalUrl +"'></iframe>";
    html += "</body></html>";       
    // open new pop up window
    YUIwinObj= window.open("", 'document', 'width=825,height=600,directories=no,status=yes,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
    YUIwinObj.document.write(html);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a self-signed certificate? If not can you share the public HTTPS url?

Comment: You only get this error when the URL is in an iframe, not when you access it directly?

Comment: This is a self signed certificate. Do you think we need any change to include IE11 in certificate.

Comment: @Barmar correct. It works well without iframe. i.e.
YUIwinObj = window.open(finalUrl, 'document', 'width=825,height=600,directories=no,status=yes,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');

Answer (score 3):

i was breaking my head for weeks , finally it is this
go to IE 11 advanced settings tab and uncheck

> "Warn about certificate address mismatch"

Answer (score 0):

It was the issue with self-signed certificate. Due to enhanced security features of IE11, it was not allowing a https.

It worked fine for a session when I installed a certificate for the IE11.

http://esupport.trendmicro.com/solution/en-US/1103987.aspx

It works well with an certificate issued by CA or other organizations.

Thanks

Arun